# Writing ArrayList object in a file

Tags: java, file, arraylist

My objective is to create a function which will write an *Arraylist* of **Account**(my class) type in a file. I have written the following code but the *ArrayList* **myList** is only adding the details specified in the second run of the loop twice..Plus for the second run it just skips the **name** field entry to **ac**.

```
public void builIT(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Account> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    Account a = new Account();
    String name = null;
    String ac = null;
    String phone = null;
    String email = null;
    String password = null;
    double balance = 0;
    try{
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("c:\\Users\\srawa\\Desktop\\thisisit");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){                
            System.out.print("Name:");
                name=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("ACNO:");
                ac=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Phone:");
                phone=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Email:");
                email=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Password:");
                password=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Balance:");
                balance=sc.nextDouble();
            a.set(name,ac,phone,email,password,balance);
            System.out.println(a);
            myList.add(a);               
            System.out.println(myList);
        }

        oos.writeObject(myList);
        oos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Please help. Thank you.
P.S.- I'm new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: How many times do you call `new Account()`. What do you deduce on the number of **different** accounts the list contains? Advice: instead of using `set()` to set all the fields of your account, use a constructor. That will make your mistake impossible. And you will never have an account containing nothing.

Comment: Double duplicate :) Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way.

Comment: @cricket_007 umm.. then can i get the link to the original quesiton..

Comment: @JBNizet ok i changed the set to the constructor..all is ok..but its still skipping the step of inputting the name field for the second run of the loop. :/

Comment: Read the duplicate questions.